# Why is this kind of adjective called "positive"?

Tags: adjectives

According to many sites and books, adjectives are classified into three groups:

- **positive**
- **comparative**
- **superlative**

While I understand well why the last two are called "comparative" and "superlative" I don't understand at all why the other form is called positive (while in fact it can be as well as negative such as bad etc)

[image]

Comment: I've no special knowledge of this terminology, or how widespread it is. But the obvious interpretation is that, say, ***thin*** is a "positive, definite" assertion concerning an attribute (it's not "middling, neither thick nor thin", and it's *certainly* not "fat"). So the table could just as well have featured ***fat*** as a positive assertion (of not being thin). It's not a "value judgement". Besides which, ***fat*** isn't always bad even for non-fetishists. Everyone wants ***a fat pay-check***, even [*Slim Pickens*](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001620/).

Comment: Normally, it's adjective, comparative and superlative. They just decided to call it that. There is no good reason for it.

Comment: @Lambie Remember comments are to suggest improvements or corrections to questions. Your answer written in a comment is wrong. There is a reason.

Answer (score 5):

"Positive" in this context is a grammarian's term that just means "base form"; the positive form is the base form of the adjective. The word does not carry any implications of goodness or praiseworthiness, thus you can have bad (base or positive) worse (comparative) and worst (superlative).

Comment: [wiktionary - positive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/positive#Adjective) sense 10

Comment: @Michael I understand that it means prymary, but what is the relation between  positive and primary? Why did they choose such unnclear term apparently?

Comment: @James it make sense that this sense of "positive" is based on the context of positive not by accident. There is some reason for that.

Comment: "Positive" has the sense "absolute". It still has this meaning in some philosophical contexts (sense 11: "The idea of beauty is not positive, but depends on the different tastes of the individual"). The base form of an adjective is the absolute form. Comparative and superlative have a relative meaning. @michael, you could [edit] to include some of the etymology that the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The positive sense indicates that the noun modified by the adjective has the characteristic referred to by the adjective.  If X is a noun and a is an adjective modifying X then one could say X is or has a. Only one word, in this case x, is involved.  For example, "He is strong."  It is positive in the sense that the subject positively has the attribute.  It can, however, be a negative attribute, for example "He is weak."
The comparative form allows you to state who has more or the most of the given modifier among a group to which the attribute applies.  Hence if X, Y, and Z are a then they are all a-ish, but X is a-er than Y and Z so x is a-est.